# Android background service notification not sending parameters to phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, service, background, notifications

I have an App build in phonegap 5.0 that also has a background service which triggers notifications. Everything works fine except that when I click the notification, the app opens like it should be, but I can´t get any parameters from the notification. In phonegap I use this [local.notification.plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) to get info from local notification, but only works if the notification is added from the app, not from background services.

Is there something that I missed? Has anybody had the same problem?

This is my Android service code:

```
public class MyService extends BackgroundService {

private void showNotification(int _nid, String _id, Date _now, String contentTitle, String contentText) {
    _log=_log+_now.toString()+" activada notificacion"+contentTitle;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                    .setContentText(contentText);
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = _nid;

    Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_sound);
    builder.setSound(alarmSound);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
    if(_id.equals("0")){
    }else{
        File theImg = new File("https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/iloveit/promo/" + _id + ".jpg");
        if(!theImg.exists()) {
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(getBitmapFromURL("https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/iloveit/promo/" + _id + ".jpg")));
        }
    }
    //builder.setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromURL("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhp07tKX-yadhAnHJXd5_oxHMtbYBhxvOeLqsEypSdFq5zThwiLg"));

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}}
```

Comment: what parameters do you mean?

Comment: like for example the notification "id" ... or title o text, but the id is significant to know what page show in the app..

Comment: the "parameters" are called "extras" and you should pass them in your `Intent`

Comment: can you post a example code please!! tnks i dont know how to pass extras

Comment: so read the basics: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building

Comment: thanks but not sure that that is the problem, the data is embedded in the notification already...but i just can´t get to it from phonegap or cordova app!!